# Selenium webdriver- How to do indexing to xapth

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have UI where I need to check the checkbox to open another window.
But these checkboxes are defined as images and the unique locator is

```
//img[@src='https://myvoice-preprod.primus.ca/HPBX/hpbx/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/DynamicForm/unchecked.png'] 

List<WebElement>lChekbox =  driver.findElements(By.xpath
                ("//img[@src='https://myvoice-preprod.primus.ca/HPBX/hpbx/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/DynamicForm/unchecked.png']"));

        int iChk = lChekbox.size();
        for(int i =0; i<=iChk; i++){
            if (i==index){

            }
        }
```

index= Index of row in table to which desired check-box belongs to.

How to click on this checkbox/image based upon index or how to pass the index to this xpath

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually, you have a `list<WebElement>` named lChekbox that contains all img that checkbox is uncheck.

Get all your images here :

```
List<WebElement> lChekbox =  driver.findElements(By.xpath
            ("//img[@src='https://myvoice-preprod.primus.ca/HPBX/hpbx/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/DynamicForm/unchecked.png']"));
```

And then loop it until you get `i==index`

```
int iChk = lChekbox.size();
for(int i =0; i<=iChk; i++){
  if (i==index){
    lChekbox.get(i).click();
  }
}
```

`.get()` -> returns the element at position i

Comment: @Rakesh Yeah !! Don't forget to validate de answer =)